# Changing displayed Android device name in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device

When attaching several Android devices to my development machine, it quickly becomes difficult to determine which device is which from Eclipse, because the device names appear to be represented as their serial numbers.

For instance, the Devices list:
[image]

Is there any way to display the phone model, or to change the device name?

Comment: I was wondering about that sometime ago. Didn't find any. The worst case scenario is to just submit a patch for `adb` or `ADT` that implements that feature and wait for the next release :)

Comment: Yep, +1 too. In the meantime you have the Android version in case you are testing on different SDK platforms (here 2.2.2 and 2.1-updat...).

Comment: @inazaruk Patching `adb` might not be a bad idea, but I have the impression that will be a lot of work. @MarvinLabs Unfortunately, there are three phones here with 2.1-update1. I suppose it will be memorizing the serial numbers for the time being.

Comment: Looks like `adb` doesn't need any patching at all. You can grab the device model from it via: `adb -s <serialno> shell getprop ro.product.model`. It might be possible to implement this as a patch for `ADT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ADT revision 17, the device manufacturer and name appears after the serial number, as follows:

[image: Screenshot of Devices tab in ADT rev 17]

Comment: Though not exactly useful when you have two phones which are the same. I'm starting to memorise their serial numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

On my Desire (cyanogenmod7, Android 2.3.3) there is a setting:

Homescreen -> press menu -> System settings -> applications -> development -> Device name

Here I can change the devices name which is shown in eclipse.

Unfortunately, my second development phone (Nexus-S, Stock rom with Android 2.3.4) does not have this setting - so maybe your phone has this setting...?!

Comment: Seems like this is one of the neat features Cyanogen added. I don't have this setting on any of my stock dev phones (HTC, Samsung or LG).

Comment: i had this same problem as the question, but changing my device name as user727035 suggests had no impact on what eclipse showed :(

Comment: Confirmation. I use Cyanogenmod 7 on my Nexus one. I have this capability in Settings>Applications>Development>Device hostname

Comment: thats odd that it works for some models and not others. but i suppose thats what happens when you use a custom rom.

Answer (score -2):

Try these commands:

```
adb -s <serialno> shell setprop persist.usb.serialno <new_alphanumeric_name>
adb reboot
```

Bear in mind that the size is maximally 15 characters.

Comment: sorry, typo the correct one is "adb -s device_name_to_change shell setprop persist.usb.serialno new_device_name_in_alphanumberic_only" and then do adb reboot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a swing, but it's still displaying the serial number. You might be on to something, but it didn't work for my (rooted) Gingerbread device.